# Timeline Matrix (Theoretical Animating)

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, shape-keys, timeline

I haven't been active for a while, but something has come up that I am really intrigued about.

Would it be possible, to have two animation sequences for one mesh rig, and then use python to animate "shape keys" between those two animation sequences?

For example, if I had a walking animation for a character, and a running animation for the same character, could I use python to create an animation sequence which is somewhere between the two already created, like having a shape-key between two key-frames?

I'm not sure how else to explain this, and it may not be possible, but if it is, some ideas would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: If this can be done, it will then be possible to animate a smooth transition between any two points of an animation (such as a walk cycle) in real time. For example, it will then be possible to create a smooth transition within a game between a characters standing walk cycle and their crouching walk cycle.